# Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin but there is enough overlap between Kotlin and the previous language Android used (a weird mix of mangled Java and XML) that recognize what I'm doing. I got this error

````
```java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.durationv1/com.example.durationv1.MainActivity}: 
                                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference```
````

when I ran the following code (which did not start at all):

````
   import android.os.Bundle
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
   import android.widget.Button
   import android.widget.EditText
   import android.widget.TextView
   import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   import java.time.LocalDate
   import java.time.Period
   import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter


   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
       var date1: EditText = findViewById(R.id.TextDate1)
       var date2: EditText = findViewById(R.id.TextDate2)
       var dateButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.GetDateLength)
       val constraintLayout:ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout)
       val DateLengthtv:TextView = findViewById(R.id.displayDateLength)
       var textDate1 = date1.getText().toString().trim()
       var textDate2 = date2.getText().toString().trim()
       var td1: LocalDate = LocalDate.parse(textDate1, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm/dd/yyyy"))
       var td2: LocalDate = LocalDate.parse(textDate2, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm/dd/yyyy"))
       val period: Period = Period.between(td1, td2)
       var daysbetween: Int = period.days
       var monthsbetween: Int = period.months
       var yearsbetween: Int = period.years
       //var dateString1: Period = "The time Between these days is: $yearsbetween, $monthsbetween, $daysbetween"

           override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
           constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
           dateButton.setOnClickListener {DateLengthtv.setText(R.string.datedisplaylength)}
       }
   }```


The code is supposed to show two edittext boxes that let the user choose two dates and a button that, when pressed, shows the length of time between the user's chosen dates. 

I expected two editText boxes, a textview box, and a button. Instead, the program didn't make it past starting the emulator. I know the error has something to do with Context, but I am not entirely sure what. Context appeared as part of the prewritten code when I ran programs in the past with Java but it did not appear for Kotlin. Was I supposed to add it myself? If so, where? And what should it be doing?
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Sort of. It helps me understand what I did wrong, but I don't know what Context is supposed to do, where it's supposed to go in the code, or what it's supposed to hold.